# I have a CSV file where the Date and the time are into 2 fields. How can I use FileHelpers to aggregate the 2 fields into the same DateTime data?

Tags: c#, csv, filehelpers

I have a CSV file where the Date and the time are into 2 fields.
How can I use FileHelpers to aggregate the 2 fields into the same DateTime data ?

Thanks,

```
2011.01.07,09:56,1.2985,1.2986,1.2979,1.2981,103
2011.01.07,09:57,1.2981,1.2982,1.2979,1.2982,75
2011.01.07,09:58,1.2982,1.2982,1.2976,1.2977,83
2011.01.07,09:59,1.2977,1.2981,1.2977,1.2980,97
2011.01.07,10:00,1.2980,1.2980,1.2978,1.2979,101
2011.01.07,10:01,1.2980,1.2981,1.2978,1.2978,57
2011.01.07,10:02,1.2978,1.2979,1.2977,1.2978,86
2011.01.07,10:03,1.2978,1.2978,1.2973,1.2973,84
2011.01.07,10:04,1.2973,1.2976,1.2973,1.2975,71
2011.01.07,10:05,1.2974,1.2977,1.2974,1.2977,53
2011.01.07,10:06,1.2977,1.2979,1.2976,1.2978,57
2011.01.07,10:07,1.2978,1.2978,1.2976,1.2976,53
2011.01.07,10:08,1.2976,1.2980,1.2976,1.2980,58
2011.01.07,10:09,1.2979,1.2985,1.2979,1.2980,63
```

Comment: Is this a homework question? What have you tried?

Comment: @Ritch, I would doubt it's homework...FileHelpers is not the usual type of homework question.

Comment: @Tuzo - Fair enough, the data looks like homework to me.

Comment: What calender are you trying to represent, Gregorian? If it is a serial number as per excel, what base date are you working from?

Answer (score 0):

```
var file = @"2011.01.07,09:56,1.2985,1.2986,1.2979,1.2981,103
2011.01.08,09:57,1.2981,1.2982,1.2979,1.2982,75
2011.01.09,09:58,1.2982,1.2982,1.2976,1.2977,83
2011.01.07,09:59,1.2977,1.2981,1.2977,1.2980,97
2011.01.07,10:00,1.2980,1.2980,1.2978,1.2979,101
2011.01.07,10:01,1.2980,1.2981,1.2978,1.2978,57
2011.01.07,10:02,1.2978,1.2979,1.2977,1.2978,86
2011.01.07,10:03,1.2978,1.2978,1.2973,1.2973,84
2011.01.07,10:04,1.2973,1.2976,1.2973,1.2975,71
2011.01.07,10:05,1.2974,1.2977,1.2974,1.2977,53
2011.01.07,10:06,1.2977,1.2979,1.2976,1.2978,57
2011.01.07,10:07,1.2978,1.2978,1.2976,1.2976,53
2011.01.07,10:08,1.2976,1.2980,1.2976,1.2980,58
2011.01.07,10:09,1.2979,1.2985,1.2979,1.2980,63";

var rows = file.Split('\n');
foreach(var row in rows){
    var cols = row.Split(',');
    var col1 = new DateTime();
    foreach(var col in cols){
        if (col == cols[0]) // first col
        {
            var dateParts = col.Split('.');
            col1 = new DateTime(int.Parse(dateParts[0]), int.Parse(dateParts[1]), int.Parse(dateParts[2]));
        }
        else if (col == cols[1]) // second col
        {
            var timeParts = col.Split(':');
            col1 = col1.AddHours(int.Parse(timeParts[0]));
            col1 = col1.AddMinutes(int.Parse(timeParts[1]));
            //col1.Dump();
        }
        else {
                // all other columns here
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Josiah Ruddell,

I find this answer usefull, but I cant vote (I need 15 to vote).
But I dont choose it because it dont use FileHelpers.

Answer (score 0):

I answer my own question.
Because my need have change, I dont really answer my own question.
My question have evolve to :
I have a CSV file where the Date and the time are into 2 fields. How can I use FileHelpers to aggregate the 2 fields into the same XLDate data ?

Here the full projet where I use this code :
[enter link description here](http://code.google.com/p/everychart/)

```
        private void CreateGraphic(ZedGraphControl zgc)
    {
        // référence vers le "canevas"
        GraphPane pane = zgc.GraphPane;

        pane.Title.Text = "Japanese Candlestick Chart Demo";
        pane.XAxis.Title.Text = "Trading Date";
        pane.YAxis.Title.Text = "Share Price, $US";

        FileHelperEngine<MetaTrader4> engine = new FileHelperEngine<MetaTrader4>();

        engine.ErrorManager.ErrorMode = ErrorMode.SaveAndContinue;

        MetaTrader4[] res = engine.ReadFile(@"..\..\Data\EURUSD240.csv");

        if (engine.ErrorManager.ErrorCount > 0)
            engine.ErrorManager.SaveErrors("Errors.txt");

        StockPointList spl = new StockPointList();

        foreach (MetaTrader4 quotes in res)
        {
            DateTime dateTime = new DateTime();
            dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(quotes.Date + "-" + quotes.Time, "yyyy.MM.dd-HH:mm",
                                             null);

            XDate xDate = new XDate(dateTime);
            StockPt pt = new StockPt(xDate, quotes.Hight, quotes.Low, quotes.Open, quotes.Close, quotes.Volume);
            spl.Add(pt);
        }

        JapaneseCandleStickItem myCurve = pane.AddJapaneseCandleStick("trades", spl);
        myCurve.Stick.IsAutoSize = true;
        myCurve.Stick.Color = Color.Blue;

        // Use DateAsOrdinal to skip weekend gaps
        pane.XAxis.Type = AxisType.DateAsOrdinal;

        // pretty it up a little
        pane.Chart.Fill = new Fill(Color.White, Color.LightGoldenrodYellow, 45.0f);
        pane.Fill = new Fill(Color.White, Color.FromArgb(220, 220, 255), 45.0f);

        zgc.AxisChange();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You do this by listening to the engine.BeforeReadRecord event.

As you (engine) read each line, you'll need to remove the delimiter between the date and time so that it fits the expected date time format you specified in the FieldConverter attribute.

Here's is a linqpad snippet to demonstrate.

```
void Main()
{
    string reading = "2011.01.07,09:56,1.2985,1.2986,1.2979,1.2981,103";

    var engine = new FileHelperEngine<Reading>();

//engine.Options.Fields.Dump();

    char delimiter = ((DelimitedRecordOptions)engine.Options).Delimiter.ToCharArray().First();

    int expectedDelimiterCount = engine.Options.Fields.Sum(field => field.FieldType == typeof(DateTime) ? 2 : field.ArrayMinLength == 0 ? 1 : field.ArrayMinLength);

    expectedDelimiterCount--; // no ending delimiter

    engine.BeforeReadRecord += (ngin, e) => {

        int fieldCount = e.RecordLine.Count(c => c == delimiter);

        if (fieldCount == expectedDelimiterCount)
        {
            int delimiterIndex = e.RecordLine.IndexOf(delimiter);

            if (delimiterIndex > NOT_FOUND)
            {
                e.RecordLine = e.RecordLine.Remove(delimiterIndex, 1);          
            }
        }

    };


    var readings = engine.ReadString(reading);

    readings.Dump();

}

const int NOT_FOUND = -1;

// Define other methods and classes here
[DelimitedRecord(",")]
class Reading
{
    [FieldOrder(1)] 
    [FieldConverter(ConverterKind.Date, "yyyy.MM.ddHH:mm")]
    public DateTime CollectionDate { get; set; }

    [FieldOrder(2)] 
    [FieldArrayLength(4)]
    public decimal[] Data;

    [FieldOrder(3)] 
    public int CollectorID { get; set; }
}
```

Writing out the DateTime property into two fields is left as an exercise for the reader.